# Select statement using AND

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of answers with column fields like:

```
questionID,answer,email
row1: questionID = 'q1', answer = 'Male', email = 'fake@fake.com'
row2: questionID = 'q2', answer = 'Human',email = 'fake@fake.com'
```

I want to have a select statement like this:

```
SELECT email 
FROM answers 
WHERE (questionID='q1' AND answer='Male') 
    AND (questionID='q2' AND answer='Human')
```

So in other words, I want to the email of all of the people that are male, and human. The thing is each 'answer' is a new row so this query does not work. Is there a way to do this easily? Thanks!

Comment: This will not work because questionID cannot have a value of 'q1' and 'q2' at the same time. You need to use `OR` instead

Comment: The problem is I have unique questions that might have the same answer in a different questionID. Can you explain a way to do with with or? The answer given returns a result that is male but not human

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT email FROM answers 
WHERE answer='Male' OR answer='Human'
group by email 
having count(distinct answer) = 2
```

Comment: The `DISTINCT questionID` clause is to avoid counting duplicate answers, right?

Comment: This returned a result of an email address the had answered Male, but not human

Comment: I had to add group by email to the end to make it work the first time. I tried the new one and got the error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by email LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4"

Comment: Your error message tells me that you don't use my query exactly. Can you provide an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) example?

Comment: Sorry. I switched the group and where clause. Corrected it here and in the answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cea3/3

Comment: I made a quick change it should be q1,q2,q1,q2

Comment: PERFECT THANK YOU. Works the way I want I appreciate it!